# How to toggle display of two elements in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

We are trying to toggle display of two elements when clicked on first element i.e, when I clicked on thumbnail I want to display video of that thumbnail only and hide that thumbnail and remaining thumbnails should be unchanged.

HTML Code

```html
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="video in videos" >
<div class="item item-image">
   <img ng-src="{{video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url}}" ng-click="displayvideo(this)">
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="display : none;" id="vid1">
       <youtube-video class="embed-responsive-item" video-id="video.id.videoId" player-vars="playerVars"></youtube-video>
   </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS Code

```
$scope.displayvideo = function(this){
    this.style.display = none;
    var ele = angular.element('#vid1');
    ele.style.display = float;
}
```

Comment: The HTML Code is not visible. Kindly edit.

Comment: If you are using AngularJS don't manipulate DOM. Use `ng-show` / `ng-hide` / `ng-if`

Comment: Agreed with @Weedoze

Comment: refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="item item-image">
   <img ng-show="!isvideoPlaying" ng-src="{{video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url}}" ng-click="displayvideo()">
   <div ng-show="isvideoPlaying" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="display : none;" id="vid1">
   <youtube-video class="embed-responsive-item" video-id="video.id.videoId" player-vars="playerVars"></youtube-video>
</div>
</div>
```

AngularJS Code

```html
$scope.isvideoPlaying = false;
$scope.displayvideo = function(){
   $scope.isvideoPlaying = true;
}
```

Comment: thank for reply.there is a ng-repeat before this code.how can i apply this logic to that particular element only and not for all

Comment: Add a property in your "video" object. Something like video.IsPlaying. Use that to toggle the view in ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-show / ng-hide / ng-if` is best way, but for now you use something like this,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="item item-image">
   <img ng-src="{{video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url}}" ng-click="displayvideo(video)">
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" ng-style="video.myStyle" id="vid1">
       <youtube-video class="embed-responsive-item" video-id="video.id.videoId" player-vars="playerVars"></youtube-video>
   </div>
</div>
```

In controller :

```
$scope.displayvideo = function(video){
    video.myStyle={'display':'none'}
}
```

If ypu want intialize `myStyle` using

```
ng-init="video.myStyle={'display':'float'}"
```

Comment: there is a ng-repeat function we are using.so how we apply  this logic to only to that particular thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="item item-image">
   <img ng-show="display" ng-src="{{video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url}}" ng-click="display=!display">
   <div ng-show="!display" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="display : none;" id="vid1" ng-click="display=!display">
       <youtube-video class="embed-responsive-item" video-id="video.id.videoId" player-vars="playerVars"></youtube-video>
   </div>
</div>
```

and set your

```
$scope.display=true;
```

Setting it to **true** **initially** will show the **Thumbnail**, on click of the thumbnail, the video ill be visible and thumbnail will be hidden.

Comment: thank for reply.there is a ng-repeat before this code.how can i apply this logic to that particular element only and not for all

Answer (score 0):

You need not write any function in the controller too. Just toggle a scope variable like below :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-repeat="video in allVideos">
<div class="item item-image">
   <img ng-src="{{video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url}}" ng-click="showVideo = true" ng-hide="video.showVideo">
   <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="display : none;" id="vid1" ng-show="video.showVideo">
       <youtube-video class="embed-responsive-item" video-id="video.id.videoId" player-vars="playerVars"></youtube-video>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In your Controller :

```
var allVideos = {"data":[{"id":{"video_id":"Vid-1"},"snippet":{"thumbnails":{"medium":{"url":"http://sampleVideoThumnail1.jpg"}}}},{"id":{"video_id":"Vid-2"},"snippet":{"thumbnails":{"medium":{"url":"http://sampleVideoThumnail2.jpg"}}}}]}
```

Assuming your videos data is something like above array, once you fetched the data, you can loop through the above array and add a new key in each object like below :

```
$scope.allVideos = allVideos.data.map(function (eachVideo){
  return eachVideo.showVideo = false;
});
```

You can have a button on the video to close the video and show thumbnail by making "showVideo" to true.

Comment: thank for reply.there is a ng-repeat before this code.how can i apply this logic to that particular element only and not for all

Comment: @kireeti You can add the same showVideo key in each object of your videos array which is ng-repeated. I've updated my answer , please check and let me know if that is what you are expecting.